# How you do use Secrets in a Connection String Azure Release Pipeline - Using Azure App Service Settings Task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am using Azure App Service Settings task in a release pipeline for a web app.  I need to set the connection string.

According to the help icon it expects JSON syntax

```
 {
    "name": "key1",
    "value": "valueabcd",
    "type": "MySql",
    "slotSetting": false
   }
```

I would like pull the "value" from either a Variable Group that I have linked to Azure Key Vault, or from KeyVault or even just a pipeline variable.  I just want it to be secure.

The problem I am running into is how to pass a variable into the JSON if its a secret. If I do something like this

```
   {
    "name": "ConnectionStringName",
    "value": "$(DBConnectionString)",
    "type": "SQLAzure",
    "slotSetting": false
   }
```

Then the connection string is literally $(DBConnectionString).  You cant remove the quotes because then its not proper JSON.  It it related to the fact that its a secret because it works fine with regular variables.  I have read a few articles about how secrets are used differntly, but have not been able to apply them what I am doing.

I am including a screenshot to help explain where I am seeing this.

[image: Screenshot from Azure Release Pipeline Task]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran release pipeline with this:

```json
[
        {
          "name": "MysqlCredentials",
          "value": "$(MySQl_ConnectionString)",
          "type": "MySql",
          "slotSetting": false
        }
      ]
```

[image]

Having variable set in Variables:

[image]

And then I got:

[image]

So if you don't have it replaced it could mean that you don't have variable defined.

I made it a secret:

[image]

And it still works:

[image]

Comment: If you make that variable "secure" it wont work.  Try clicking the lock on the variable and then run it.  For me when its made a secret then it does not transform and that is by design from what I have read

Comment: Hmm, I wonder why mine is not working.  Going to back to try now

Comment: You are 100% correct.  I tried it multiple times, but must have been making a small mistake or typo along the way and made the problem seem larger than it was.  Thank you for the help and sanity check

Comment: @washburnj No worries. I'm happy that I could help you. Could you also consider upvoting my reply if it was helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution that worked in my scenario.  I put the connection string in Vault and added the Azure Key Vault task right before my Azure App Service Settings task and then the standard variable sub worked.